# Phase 10 discard pile

Tags: phase-10

While playing Phase Ten, is it legal to pick up the top card of the discard pile and then immediately discard that exact card?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You draw the card, put it into your hand, and then discard **any** card from your hand (which may be the card you just drew).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should rather pick up a card from the pile to get a chance to help you. But if you want to do that yes you can.