# Phase 10 rules on discard pile

Tags: phase-10

In phase 10, can I pick up a card from the discard pile and then relay that card back down in the discard pile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phase 10 discard pile](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45336/phase-10-discard-pile)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The rules say that you must draw a card and that you must discard a card as part of your turn. (At least my edition) It does not state specifically about not being able to discard the draw off the discard pile.

However, I do question it as a strategy.  If the card to be picked up from the discard does not help the hand, then there is a much greater probability that the card from the draw pile will help the hand.

Comment: I can see why this could be advantageous.  Say that you and the player on the left have satisfied the phases you are on, but other players haven't.  You have two or three cards in your hand, whereas the player on your left has one.  The top card of the discard can be played on the field.  Rather than playing it yourself and hoping to find another 1-2 cards to end the round, you draw and discard the top card from the discard pile, allowing the player on your left to pick it up and end the round.  While you will gain 15-45 points (assuming 3 cards in hand), your other opponents won't progress.